# Writing Django signup form tests for checking new user creation

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-unittest, django-custom-user

Implemented a custom user model in Django and allows user to signup using the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/signup/. A GET request on this url is displayed like this:

[image]

I have written tests for this page. Tests for `get` is working as expected.

I wrote test for `post` with the intention that the post would create a user in the test database. After which I could write tests to confirm if an user is created and whether the username matches and so on. But it seems the user is not getting created. Below are my tests

```py
class SignUpPageTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.username = 'testuser'
        self.email = 'testuser@email.com'
        self.age = 20
        self.password = 'password'

    def test_signup_page_url(self):
        response = self.client.get("/users/signup/")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template_name='signup.html')

    def test_signup_page_view_name(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('signup'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template_name='signup.html')

    def test_signup_form(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('signup'), data={
            'username': self.username,
            'email': self.email,
            'age': self.age,
            'password1': self.password,
            'password2': self.password
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        users = get_user_model().objects.all()
        self.assertEqual(users.count(), 1)
```

The users.count() turns out to be 0 and my test is failing. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and realized the problem was that the form validation was failing, you can confirm manually (running the server) that if you use `password` as your password then Django complains saying `This password is too common.` So, you need to use a different password.

Also, in my test I expected a code 302 instead of 200, because I redirect after the signup.

Comment: I was using a sample password of "12345" which didn't work for me. When I specified a more complicated password, the `client.post()` worked properly.